# Error in Admin Panel

Tags: admin-panel

I found below error in Admin Panel.

[image]

I found below error messages in **debug.log** file.

```
[2020-06-25 13:48:39] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-06-25 13:48:39] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-06-25 13:48:39] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
```

How can I fix the error ?